# Python script not running correctly when launched with crontab

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, python, boot

I'm running a telegram bot on my Raspberry Pi 3. When I run it in my console or using Thonny, everything runs smoothly.

```
python3 /home/pi/Documents/telegrambot.py
```

The problem occurs when I set the program to start on boot.

```
sudo crontab -e
[last line] @reboot sudo python3 /home/pi/Documents/telegrambot.py &
```

I know that the code is running because I set the bot to send me "I'm online" and it answer me if the reply isn't related to sending images... but when I send to it /tempgraph, it should answer with the the picture of its readings.
But I only get the sensor's name and no image at all.

```
...
    chatHist = readCommandHistory(db,chat_id,1)
    lastCommand = chatHist[0]['msg']
    choice = command.split(".")
    if command in lastCommand and len(choice) <= 2:
        Fonte = re.search('(\s|\n)'+str(command.split('.')[0])+'\)\s(.*)', lastCommand).group(2)
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, Fonte) #this works
        if len(choice) == 1:
            table = sdc.readTableServer(db, senstable, 'Fonte', Fonte)
            for sensor in table.Sensor.unique():
                bot.sendMessage(chat_id, sensor) 
                tbl = table[table.Sensor == sensor]
                #until here everything is ok
                for ts in tiposensores:
                    try:
                        gop.plotSetup(tbl[['Data',ts]]) 
                        #save the image in the folter ... Images/Imagem.png, 
                        #but only works when not on stratup...
                        bot.sendPhoto(chat_id,open('/home/pi/Documents/Images/Imagem.png','rb'))
                        pif.cleanImages()
                    except OSError:
                        pass
```

...

@edit:

I found out that the problem happens after i call

```
gop.plotSetup(tbl[['Data',ts]])
```

inside the plotSetup function, in this step:

```
f= plt.figure(figsize=(12, 9))
```

This is the first time that i use the variable *f* inside the function.

@edit2

As I said before, the error happens in the plt.figure.

THis is the gpo.plotSetup(), with some changes to catch the error as instructed:

```
def plotSetup(Data):
...[some code here]...
    with open("/home/pi/Desktop/log.csv","a+") as o:
        fop.writeCSVFile(o, ['before first plt.figure'])

        try:
            f= plt.figure(figsize=(12, 9))
        except IOError as e:
            fop.writeCSVFile(o, e)
        except:
            for e in sys.exc_info():
                fop.writeCSVFile(o, e)

...[some code here]...
    f.savefig("/home/pi/Documents/Images/Imagem.png", bbox_inches="tight")
```

and i got this errors:

```
<class '_tkinter.TclError'>
no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
<traceback object at 0x6e3c8d50>
```

@edit3

That error led me to this post:

[_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604289/tkinter-tclerror-no-display-name-and-no-display-environment-variable)

this post suggested use this in the very beginning of the code:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

and then *VOILA*!! It's alive.

Really appreciate all the help that you guys gave me, thanks! ;p

Comment: Does this `gop.PlotSetup` generate a picture and store it on disk?

Comment: Edit the crontab without "sudo": `$ crontab -e`

Comment: @MarkSmith, yeah it does! I'll add the last line of this function in the post.

Comment: @BenyaminJafari, tried this too, everything runs in the same way as before (sending pictures still not working) =(

Comment: Debug the python script to a log file and check the errors after booting. Make sure you use chmod -R,  recursive.

Comment: @PedroLobito, where should i use chmod -r?

Comment: On the folder(s) where you want to store/run images/scripts

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$ sudo chmod 777 /home/pi/Documents/Images
```

After you've done that, re-boot to check if that fixes it.
If not, try changing your `crontab` entry to this:

```
@reboot ( /bin/sleep 30; /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Documents/telegrambot.py >> /home/pi/Desktop/log.txt 2>&1)
```

You should also consider adding a debug statement to your Python code to collect and save any errors that are thrown during execution.

Comment: I thied this with no success. =/. Also changed the crontab code to:
    @reboot python3 /home/pi/Documents/telegrambot.py & /home/pi/Desktop/log.txt >&1
to get some error log, but nothing happened.

Comment: @SWoto: I'll edit my answer; check back shortly. In the meantime, what is the purpose of the stuff on your crontab: [Ctrl+X -> Y -> Enter] ?

Comment: @Seamnu: i tried what u said and it didn't solve the problem. But i've some more info (i'll add it in the post too). The problem happens inside this funciton: gop.plotSetup(tbl[['Data',ts]]), right here f= plt.figure(figsize=(12, 9)). This is the first time using the variable 'f' and plt comes from import matplotlib.pyplot as plt. So the problem lies in the plt, not in the folter permission, because the saving step is the last thing inside the plotSetup function.

Comment: @SWoto: Hopefully the answer from Mark Smith has resolved your issue. Do let us know if you're still stuck. If you did get an answer here that resolved your issue, please consider designating it as the "correct answer" by ticking the check box next to that answer.

Answer (score 4):

You have two problems: the problem of the file not being found, and the problem preventing you from debugging the first problem.

First let's make a general improvement.  You have

```
try:
    [...]
except OSError e:
    pass
```

This means if the `try` part fails with `OSError`, it will just ignore it, tell you nothing about it, and carry on.  At very least, log the error:

```
try:
    [...]
except OSError e:
    print(e)
```

Now when it goes wrong you should be able to find out why from the system logs (`/var/log/syslog` I think).

Now the real problem.  I don't know what this `gop` thing is, and your extract doesn't show it, but you say it generates a file, which you indicate is in `Images/Imagem.png` -- although I suspect it's really in `Documents/Images/Imagem.png`.  This is a relative path - relative to your current directory.  When you load the file in the next line, you use an absolute path - relative to the filesystem root.

When you run the file as user `pi` you are probably doing so from `/home/pi` (or `~pi`, which is equivalent), your file goes into `/home/pi/Documents/Images/Imagem.png`, the absolute and relative paths happen to match up, and the next line can find the file.  However when you run it from `crontab`, it will have a different current directory.  I don't know offhand what current directory `crontab` will give it, but there's no way it'll be `/home/pi`.

Either change `gop` (whatever that is) to put the file in an absolute location (I don't have the code to help with that), or change your code to read it from the same relative location:

```
bot.sendPhoto(chat_id,open('Documents/Images/Imagem.png','rb'))
```

Lastly, unless there is a good reason to run the script as root, don't.  It should have the least privilege it requires to work.  Just good practice.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a permission problem. When running under the user's (your) credentials it works and when under the crontab's credentials is does not.

Try a test: WRT to your images, temporarily open permissions to all images files and the associated directory and see if the application works when run by the crontab.

Don't leave the permissions opened to all as it is a security risk.

Comment: I thied this ($ sudo chmod 777 /home/pi/Documents/Images ) with no success. =/. Also changed the crontab code to:
    @reboot python3 /home/pi/Documents/telegrambot.py & /home/pi/Desktop/log.txt >&1
to get some error log, but nothing happened.

Comment: There may also be an issue with the path you use and the path which is used when running a crontab job.  But since you indicated the python script was running I didn't mention it.    Also, use complete paths to files avoiding problems associated with variables like "$HOME" or paths which start with "~".

Comment: just eddited the post. I found that the problem lies here: f= plt.figure(figsize=(12, 9)), inside the plotSetup function. I tried the complete paths too, like u and Seamus said: reboot ( /bin/sleep 30; /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Documents/telegrambot.py >> /home/pi/Desktop/log.txt 2>&1), but the problem persists.

Answer (score 2):

like i said in the last edition that i made in the question...

After adding the print sentence to some file after the exception, i got this:

```
<class '_tkinter.TclError'>
no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
<traceback object at 0x6e3c8d50>
```

Thit error led me to this post:

[_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604289/tkinter-tclerror-no-display-name-and-no-display-environment-variable)

that suggested to use this in the very beginning of the code:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

and then *VOILA*!! It's alive.

Really appreciate all the help that you guys gave me, thanks [@Seamus](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/83790/seamus), [@Mark Smith](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/43300/mark-smith) and [@st2000](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/45831/st2000)!! ;p

Comment: It looks like you created two accounts by mistake. Please [ask support](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge them, then you'll be able to edit your own question again.